# Maximal intersecting families on $\omega$ that are not ultrafilters

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, ultrafilters

A family ${\cal S}\subseteq{\cal P}(\omega)$ is *intersecting* if any two members of ${\cal S}$ have non-empty intersection. [Zorn's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma) implies that every intersecting family is contained in a maximal intersecting family with respect to set inclusion $\subseteq$.

Every [ultrafilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) on $\omega$ is maximal intersecting. Let ${\frak U}$ be the collection of ultrafilters on $\omega$, and let ${\frak M}$ be the collection of maximal intersecting families on $\omega$. We have ${\frak U}\subseteq {\frak M}$ and $|{\frak U}| = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

**Question.** Is $|{\frak M}\setminus{\frak U}| = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $U,V,W$ be three distinct ultrafilters on $\omega$. Let $M$ be the family of those subsets of $\omega$ that belong to at least two of $U,V,W$. Then $M$ is a maximal intersecting family, it is not an ultrafilter, and we can get $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ such $M$'s by choosing different $U,V,W$.